# OAuth Access To Google Drive Authorisation Issue

Tags: php, curl, oauth, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to create a web app that looks in my Google Drive account and provides a list of file links. I don't want to have to authorise the login each time so I am using offline mode to buypass the generation of the refresh token each time.

Using the oAuth Playground I have generated my Refresh Token and am trying to return the full list of file properties but I am getting the error message 'An error occurred: The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.Array ( ) '. Even though I generate an access token directly before submitting my request.

I am pretty sure I am doing the first bit correctly as my curl request is returning with the token details containing access token. Is there something with the second bit I am doing wrong?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"refresh_token=MyRefreshTokenFromOAuthPlayground&client_id=MyClientID&client_secret=MyClientSecret&grant_type=refresh_token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$myjson = json_decode($server_output,true);         
//at this point if I show $myjson['access_token'] I am given what looks like a valid access token.

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('MyClientID');
$client->setClientSecret('MyClientSecret');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground');
$client->setScopes(array(
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setAccessToken($server_output); //the results of the curl request
$client->setUseObjects(true);
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);


echo print_r(retrieveAllFiles($service)); //this is the sample function in the API documentation that gives the full list of file properties. It is this command that causes the error.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google APIs PHP client library adds the extra field `created` to the token object when it performs the authorization flow, and it uses the `created` and `expires_in` fields to [determine if the token is still valid](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php#L402). If the `created` field is missing, the token is assumed to be invalid. You could set this field yourself, but a better solution is to just use the existing features of the library to do all of the token fetching for you.

```
$client->refreshToken('MyRefreshTokenFromOAuthPlayground');
```